# Comparing expressions involving square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This is probably a very easy question, and one regarding domains more than any particular kind of failure for mathematica to provide the answer I expect. However  my question is;

Why does mathematica say sqrt[g*h] === sqrt[g] * sqrt[h] is false ?

Of course with numbers from the whole numbers, this is absolutely true

[image]

My expectations are that this is actually something I'm misunderstanding about how *Mathematica* deals with variables, How Simplify works...or I'm missing something in my math knowledge I didn't consider like the possible domains *Mathematica* assumes.

Comment: Evaluate each of those expressions alone to check. Without any assumptions about `g` and `h` it won't change. And that is good because the first expression is not true in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the numbers are both negative, then it is not true.

$$
\sqrt{\left(  -3\right)  \left(  -4\right)  }=\sqrt{12}%
$$

But

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\left(  -3\right)  }\sqrt{\left(  -4\right)  }  & =\left(  i\sqrt
{3}\right)  \left(  i\sqrt{4}\right)  \\
& =i^{2}\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4}\\
& =-\sqrt{12}
\end{align*}

Since $\sqrt{12}\neq-\sqrt{12}$ that is why Mathematica says False for the general case.